# Draw majorGridLine Sactter Plot - CorePlot

Tags: ios5, core-plot

I'm trying draw my line chart. But i cant drawn majorgridline.
When i custom x axis label, all majorgridline not show. And how to hid y axis lable.
Here is my line chart:
[enter link description here](http://i711.photobucket.com/albums/ww116/vxhonghui/Untitled.png)

help me draw it like:
[enter link description here](http://s711.beta.photobucket.com/user/vxhonghui/media/Untitled2.png.html)

- MajorGridLine
- custome xaxis lable, and hide yaxis lable.
  Thank.

Here is my code:

```
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

CGRect bounds = layerHostingView.bounds;

// Create the graph and assign the hosting view.
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
layerHostingView.hostedGraph = graph;
[graph applyTheme:theme];

graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;

// chang the chart layer orders so the axis line is on top of the bar in the chart.
NSArray *chartLayers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypePlots],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeMajorGridLines], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeMinorGridLines],  
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisLines], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisLabels], 
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisTitles], 
                        nil];
graph.topDownLayerOrder = chartLayers;    
[chartLayers release];


// Add plot space for horizontal bar charts
graph.paddingLeft = 50.0;
graph.paddingTop = 25.0;
graph.paddingRight = 50.0;
graph.paddingBottom = 60.0;


// Setup plot space
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
plotSpace.delegate = self;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(7)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(1000)];

// Setup grid line style
CPTMutableLineStyle *majorXGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
majorXGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
majorXGridLineStyle.dashPattern =  CPTLinearBlendingMode;
majorXGridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:64/255.0 green:177/255.0 blue:219/255.0 alpha:1.0];


// Setup x-Axis.
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.majorGridLineStyle = majorXGridLineStyle;
x.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 7;
x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"1");
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
x.labelRotation =  M_PI/4;
x.visibleRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-7.0f)];
x.gridLinesRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-7.0f)];
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
NSMutableArray *labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[xAxisWeek count]];
int idx = 0;
for (NSString *week in xAxisWeek)
{
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:week textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromInt(idx);
    label.offset = 5.0f;
    label.rotation = M_PI/4;
    [labels addObject:label];
    [label release];
    idx--; 
}
x.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:labels];
[labels release];


// Setup y-Axis.
CPTMutableLineStyle *majorYGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
majorYGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
majorYGridLineStyle.dashPattern =  CPTLinearBlendingMode;
majorYGridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:87/255.0 green:142/255.0 blue:242/255.0 alpha:1.0];

CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.majorGridLineStyle = majorYGridLineStyle;
y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"200");
y.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
y.visibleRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(1000.0f)];
y.gridLinesRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-1000.0f)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the `visibleRange` or `gridLinesRange` for either axis. The default values will make the axis and grid lines extend across the plot area, which is what is shown in your second image.

If you do need to use those properties (e.g., to let the plot symbols hang outside the grid), set both to the same range.